# Get ID's for multiple inserted rows using xml input

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a query that accepts xml as the input.  How can i return all of the ID's that get created during the insert?

```
insert into Table1 
(
    FirstName, Age
)
SELECT 
    T.item.query('./FirstName').value('.', 'varchar(54)') FirstName,
    T.item.query('./Age').value('.', 'int') Age,
    FROM @Collection.nodes('/ROWS/ROW') AS T(Item)
```

I am uncertain of the best way to return the new id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs table(ID int);

INSERT INTO Table1
    (FirstName, Age)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        INTO @InsertedIDs 
    SELECT 
        T.item.query('./FirstName').value('.', 'varchar(54)') FirstName,
        T.item.query('./Age').value('.', 'int') Age,
        FROM @Collection.nodes('/ROWS/ROW') AS T(Item);

SELECT ID FROM @InsertedIDs;
```